# concurvity in presence of random smooths

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, concurvity

I am trying to fit a GAMM containing per subject random smooths using the bam function in mgcv as follows:

```
peri.gam0 <- bam(global_intDTmc ~ 
                   s(time) + s(time,subject,bs="fs",m=1), 
                 data=pd_intdft,
                 rho=ar1_est,AR.start=pd_intdft$AR.start)
```

Essentially I am asking how an outcome variable is modulated over time. When I examine the model for concurvity, I find strong asymmetric concurvity between time and the random smooths for time by subject.

```
> concurvity(peri.gam0,full=F)
$worst
                para           s(time)        s(time,subject)
para            1.0000000000   0.0001078526   1
s(time)         0.0001078526   1.0000000000   1
s(time,subject) 1.0000000000   1.0000000000   1

$observed
                para           s(time)        s(time,subject)
para            1.0000000000   0.0000078301   3.902321e-05
s(time)         0.0001078526   1.0000000000   1.582554e-03
s(time,subject) 1.0000000000   0.9997973359   1.000000e+00

$estimate
                para           s(time)        s(time,subject)
para            1.0000000000   2.111176e-05   0.01243370
s(time)         0.0001078526   1.000000e+00   0.02048989
s(time,subject) 1.0000000000   9.982492e-01   1.00000000
```

Additionally, when I look at the variance components for the smooth terms, the confidence interval for the second entry for the random smooths is quite inflated [though I don't understand what each entry for the s(time,subject) represents]:

```
                 std.dev        lower          upper
s(time)          0.0028562260   1.165445e-03   6.999925e-03
s(time,subject)1 0.0027823396   2.099721e-03   3.686877e-03
s(time,subject)2 0.0000152669   8.981685e-36   2.595040e+25
scale            0.0175509339   1.731947e-02   1.778549e-02
```

So I am wondering:

1) Is it inevitable that there will be this sort of asymmetric concurvity in the presence of random smooths, or is this a sign of a problem?

2) What does each entry for s(time,subject) output by gam.vcomp represent, and is the inflated CI for the second entry also indication of problems w/ identifiability in this model?

EDIT: In the model above, the outcome variable is mean-centered for every trial in the data. Using the original variable w/o mean-centering removes the issue w/ gam.vcomp on the second variance component for s(time,subject), so I assume that this corresponds to by-subject random intercepts?