# High concurvity with random effect terms in generalized additive mixed effects models GAMM

Tags: random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, mgcv, concurvity

I have a quick question concerning concurvity in a generalized additive mixed effects model. There are wonderful aids for identifying concurvity for GAMs not containing random effects. However, I have not seen explanations concerning high concurvity between fixed effect smooths for example s(x,bs="ts") and random effect smooths for example s(subject,bs="re"). This same question was asked before with no response [concurvity in presence of random smooths](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/409274/concurvity-in-presence-of-random-smooths).

My analysis is as follows. I have repeated measures of "res" for each area. Res is a continuous value and modeled with a gaussian distribution. I have a continuous environmental variable specific to the area in which res was recorded (z) and a continuous temperature value during the recording of res (temp). I am interested in the combined effects of temp and x on res. I therefore set up a gam as follows.

```
mod1<-gam(res~ s(z) + s(temp))
```

Because I have repeated measures I would like to included the area as a random effect. Therefore having the following model structure.

```
mod2<-gam(res~ s(z) + s(temp) + s(area,bs="re"))
```

The pairwise concurvity values between the environmental variable associated with the area (z) and the random effect (area) are near 1 in the worst case scenario. I have a few questions.

- Given that it is between a fixed and random effect, Is the high concurvity between z and area problematic?
- If the presented concurvity is problematic, what could be an alternative approach?

```
concurvity(mod2)

         para     s(temp)      s(z)   s(area)
worst       1 0.030865482 0.9430052 1.0000000
observed    1 0.004766551 0.9399573 0.2296209
estimate    1 0.017776578 0.9058069 0.1510413
```

```
concurvity(mod2,full=F)
$worst
                para      s(temp)         s(z)    s(area)
para    1.0000000000 0.0002903174 0.0004151957 1.00000000
s(temp) 0.0002903174 1.0000000000 0.0080636515 0.02601184
s(z)    0.0004151957 0.0080636515 1.0000000000 0.94272513
s(area) 1.0000000000 0.0260118411 0.9427251271 1.00000000

$observed
                para      s(temp)         s(z)      s(area)
para    1.0000000000 2.617954e-05 3.194895e-05 4.488602e-05
s(temp) 0.0002903174 1.000000e+00 7.446183e-03 1.857687e-03
s(z)    0.0004151957 1.440157e-03 1.000000e+00 2.292680e-01
s(area) 1.0000000000 2.433589e-03 9.397200e-01 1.000000e+00

$estimate
                para      s(temp)         s(z)     s(area)
para    1.0000000000 2.150218e-05 2.491193e-05 0.025074805
s(temp) 0.0002903174 1.000000e+00 5.792759e-03 0.001217245
s(z)    0.0004151957 4.562905e-03 1.000000e+00 0.125040009
s(area) 1.0000000000 1.492578e-02 9.054246e-01 1.000000000
```

https://jroy042.github.io/nonlinear/week3.html and https://eric-pedersen.github.io/mgcv-esa-workshop/slides/02-model_checking.html#/.